# npm Getting Stuck Extracting Package Dependencies for Repo

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I'm trying to get my local setup, and for some reason npm gets stuck during installation.  I've been able to get around specific packages by deleting my `package-lock-json` and installing the stuck package on it's own, but then npm gets stuck extracting some other package.  I've tried log level `silly` nothing in the output tells me what's happening.

Example of getting stuck:

```
npm i               
⸨            ░░░░░░⸩ ⠇ extract:core-js: sill extract array-unique@0.3.2
```

I have successfully installed Cypress, so it's not all npm projects.

```
nvm use 12
Now using node v12.19.0 (npm v6.14.8)
```

MacOs Catalina v10.15.7

Comment: Does your project have a `.npmrc` file included?

Comment: Also what values are returned when you enter `npm config get proxy` and `npm config get registry` in the command line?

Comment: I have a `.npmrc` in my home folder, not in the repos though.  `get proxy` returns `null`.  `get registry` returns `http://registry.npmjs.org/`.

Comment: Can you try running `npm cache clean` before you run an `npm install` and see if that helps?

Comment: `npm cache clean` doesn't work as of 5, but I have used with `--force`, still same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in this case, the repo's I was pulling require ssh creds at some point during the npm install.  I had my setup such that I was always being prompted for my ssh public key.  Once I `cached` my ssh key by creating a `.ssh/config`, the install went through fine(not sure if cache is an accurate descriptor?).

File created:

```
Host *
    UseKeychain yes
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    ForwardAgent yes
```